# jQuery Calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I have a site where we're using the jquery UI calendar.  When I click on it's button, it operates perfectly in chrome and FFox.  IE only shows the very tippy top of the control.  When I click somewhere else on the page it shows the whole calendar and then it disappears ... that would be the normal lost focus behavior.  I've tried applying several of the z-index or maxZindex hacks to this and none of them do a damn thing.  Its like it taunts me, hiding just underneath well... nothing... and then finally appearing for a flash of a second while it blurs away.

I had it encap'd inside a label, and a fieldset.  Removed both, same issue.  IE won't let me open that POC little debugger that comes with it so I can't even try to interrogate the DOM live.  I hate all IE browsers.  Down with IE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, turns out that IE really does not like this option

showAnim: 'slideDown',

Answer (score 1):

Is there some issue with where it's located on the page and you need to include jquery.bgiframe.js?

Comment: I DL'd and added bgiframe and then called bgIframe() after the calendar init.  No love.  It still stays obscured until it loses focus, then I see it for a second, then it all goes away like its supposed to during a blur.

Comment: ok, turns out that IE really does not like this option 

showAnim: 'slideDown',